# How to set color with dependencyproperty?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

This might be a stupid question, but how to set the color property of a usercontrol? Because in XAML the color is just a text field how do I have to convert the value so that I can set the brush correctly

`<MyUserControl LabelColour="#FF747474" /> 
<MyUserControl LabelColour="Red"/>`

This is how far I got. The value comes in as the text but what is the next step to convert it to a brush?

```
private static DependencyProperty LabelColourProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelColour", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object LabelColour
    {
        get { return GetValue(LabelColourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelColourProperty, value); LabelGrid.Background = (Brush)value; }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use type `object`, why not `Brush`?

Comment: No particular reason, Brush is of course better.  The question however remains how to convert the value to a brush. Is there a method that converts a text value into a valid Color object that I then can pass into "new SolidColorBrush()" or something like that?

Comment: After playing around with the code it seems it has to be object to get it to work with XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String xamlString = "<Canvas xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" Background=\"MistyRose\"/>";
Canvas c = (Canvas) System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xamlString);
SolidColorBrush mistyRoseBrush = (SolidColorBrush) c.Background;
System.Windows.Media.Color mistyRose = mistyRoseBrush.Color;
```

I think this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not expose a direct method to convert a string to a `Color`.  The closest you will get is the `Color.FromArgb` method.  See [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which contains the nearest simple code that acheives what you need (as Vinicius directly quotes from).

Personally I would just not use `object` as the property type and let XamlParser take care of it (which ulitmately you artificially have to anyway).

This is how it should look:

```
private static DependencyProperty LabelColourProperty  
        = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelColour", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnLabelColourChanged));  

private static void OnLabelColourChanged(DependencyObject source,
                           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     MyUserControl ctl = source as MyUserControl;
     if (ctl != null)
     {
         ctl.LabelGrid.Background = (Brush)e.NewValue;
     }
}

public Brush LabelColour  
{  
    get { return GetValue(LabelColourProperty) as Brush; }  
    set { SetValue(LabelColourProperty, value); }  
}
```

Note never place other code in the setter of a property that is implemented as dependency property.  When the value is set via binding (which is the whole point of implementing it as a dependency property in the first place) the `SetValue` method is used directly by-passing the normal property setter.  Hence anything you need to happen when the value changes needs to be done in the on property changed callback that the property meta data can provide.

Comment: I just tried this but I'm not sure how this is going to work when I set LabelColour in XAML. Putting any value now into LabelColour will crash the application. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: After I changed "typeof(Brush)" to "typeof(object)" I got it working. Seems to me that it has to be object after all. I will mark this as answer therefore, too.

Comment: The `typeof(Brush)` in the Register call is correct, there was a small change needed to the Getter though.